# how to stop images from stacking on top of each other

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, position

Im using angularjs to loop over an array of images and they are all getting displayed on top off each other.

```css
    .modifier-list-icon {
      left: 5px;
      position: absolute;
      top: auto;
    }

    .icon-small {
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<span ng-if="list.images" ng-repeat="image in list.images">
  <img ng-src="{{image.url}}" alt="Icon"
       class="icon-small modifier-list-icon"/>
</span>
```

this is how the images look like with the code from above.

[image]

[image]

I changed the position to `position: relative;` ^^

I want both of the images to display next to each other like the second screenshot but I want the images to be placed to the left like the first screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to prefer a flexbox solution for these kinds of things. I repeated the entry once so you can see how shorter labels will cause the right side to shrink, but all of the nested elements stay positioned:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* 
     by using display flex, we let the child containers use as much
     width as they need, and we can keep their text-alignment separate
  */
  display: flex;
}

.icon-container,
.label-container {
  /*
     flex grow is set to 1 and flex-basis to auto so that the child elements
     will stretch to use all the available horizontal space.
     one or the other could be dropped here
  */
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.icon-container>*,
.label-container>* {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.label-container {
  /* 
     creating the white space between the left-side icons and
     right-side label/icon is just a matter of having
     text-alignments
  */
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" ng-if="list.images" ng-repeat="image in list.images">
  <div class="icon-container">
    <img ng-src="{{image.url}}" alt="An icon" class="icon-small modifier-list-icon" />
    <img ng-src="{{image.url}}" alt="Also an icon" class="icon-small modifier-list-icon" />
  </div>

  <div class="label-container">
    <span>some text very long text on the right side</span>
    <img alt="another icon" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container" ng-if="list.images" ng-repeat="image in list.images">
  <div class="icon-container">
    <img ng-src="{{image.url}}" alt="An icon" class="icon-small modifier-list-icon" />
    <img ng-src="{{image.url}}" alt="Also an icon" class="icon-small modifier-list-icon" />
  </div>

  <div class="label-container">
    <span>another entry</span>
    <img alt="another icon" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position: absolute` and `position relative`, apply `display: inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code example will solve your problem. If there is any other condition, please let me know.

```css
body {
 font: 16px "Roboto", Arial, sans-serif;
}
.block {
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 0 0 20px;
}
.block h3 {
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 0 0 10px;
}
ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
}
li {
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 0 10px;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.actions {
 display: table-cell;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
.actions img {
 margin-left: 10px;
}
.actions img:first-child {
 margin-left: 0;
}
.title {
 display: table-cell;
 padding: 0 30px 0 10px;
 text-align: right;
 position: relative;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.title img {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
}
.list2 li {
 display: flex;
}
.list2 .title {
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
 <h3>List with wrap title</h3>
 <ul>
  <li>
   <div class="actions"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/583/583988.svg" width="20"></div>
   <div class="title"><span>Small Title</span><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/584/584017.svg" width="20"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
   <div class="actions"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/583/583985.svg" width="20"> <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/583/583988.svg" width="20"></div>
   <div class="title"><span>Long Title goes here Long Title goes hereLong Title goes hereLong Title goes here</span><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/584/584017.svg" width="20"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
   <div class="actions"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/583/583985.svg" width="20"> <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/583/583988.svg" width="20"> <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/583/583985.svg" width="20"> <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/583/583988.svg"
     width="20"></div>
   <div class="title"><span>Long Title with multiple action</span><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/584/584017.svg" width="20"></div>
  </li>
  <ul>
</div>
<div class="block">
 <h3>List with truncate title </h3>
 <ul class="list2">
  <li>
   <div class="actions"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/583/583988.svg" width="20"></div>
   <div class="title">Small Title<img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/584/584017.svg" width="20"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
   <div class="actions"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/583/583985.svg" width="20"> <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/583/583988.svg" width="20"></div>
   <div class="title">Long Title goes here Long Title goes hereLong Title goes hereLong Title goes here<img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/584/584017.svg" width="20"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
   <div class="actions"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/583/583985.svg" width="20"> <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/583/583988.svg" width="20"> <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/583/583985.svg" width="20"> <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/583/583988.svg"
     width="20"></div>
   <div class="title">Long Title with multiple action<img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/584/584017.svg" width="20"></div>
  </li>
  <ul>
```